# Is this equivalent to the Riemann Hypothesis?

Tags: analysis, riemann-zeta, riemann-hypothesis

By a result of Spira, we know that the Riemann Hypothesis (RH) is equivalent to the statement that $|\zeta(1-s)|$ increases as $\Re(s)$ varies on $(\frac{1}{2}, \infty)$ with $|t|=|\Im(s)|\geq 165$ fixed.

Since $|\zeta(s)|$ is continuous, decreasing for $\Re(s)>1$ and $s$ is a zero of $\zeta$ whenever $(1-s)$ is a zero, Spira's result entails that the RH is equivalent to the statement that $|\zeta(s)|$ decreases as $\Re(s)$ varies on $(\frac{1}{2}, \infty)$ with $|t|=|\Im(s)|\geq 165$ fixed.

A combination of these two statements seems to yield another equivalent statement for the RH, namely: *The RH is equivalent to the statement that $F(s)=\frac{|\zeta(s)|}{|\zeta(1-s)|}$ decreases as $\Re(s)$ varies on $(1/2, 1]$  with $|t|=|\Im(s)|\geq 165$ fixed ?

Comment: Increasing/decreasing along what path?

Comment: @Dzoooks, i had forgotten to add certain details, please see the present form of the question.

Comment: [Riemann's functional equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_zeta_function#Riemann%27s_functional_equation) gives a simple relation between $\zeta(s)$ and $\zeta(1-s)$ namely $\frac{\zeta(s)}{\zeta(1-s)} = 2^s\pi^{s-1}\ \sin\left(\frac{\pi s}{2}\right)\ \Gamma(1-s)$

Comment: btw it's a one way implication if $|\zeta(s)|$ is decreasing and $|\zeta(1-s)|$ is increasing $\implies $ $F(s)$ is decreasing. You don't get the other way so it's not an equivalent formulation.

Comment: @Winther, basing on the fact that Spira didn't use any other property of $\zeta$ besides the functional equation, i wouldn't perceive the functional equation as a ''simple'' relation between $\zeta(s)$ and $\zeta(1-s)$.

Comment: What I meant is that $F(s)$ is a fairly simple function due to the functional equation.

Comment: @Winther, it seems to me that if $\sigma_0 \in  \mathbb{R}$ denotes the boundary of the zero-free region for the Riemann zeta function, then $\sigma_0$ can be regarded as the least possible value of $\sigma=\Re(s)$ such that $F(s)$ is decreasing. Isn't it ?